# Privileges page on Teams is unlinked

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams, help-center, privileges

A while ago, I was wondering what the exact reputation levels for privileges on a Team are. When you don't have enough reputation for all privileges, you can find out via your profile:

[image]

and from there go to the general privileges page, but on Teams you soon have all privileges and this doesn't work. You have to remember/guess that the correct URL is (substitute `moderators` with your team name) `https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/help/privileges` – there's no Team-specific Help Center page where you can find it. Or is there another way (hence the [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) tag)?

Comment: I added this bug to our tracker but it's going to go on the backlog for now so I can't commit to an ETA.